# Network problems with Samsung Galaxy Young (S6312)

Tags: calls, connection-issues, data-connection, mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-y

I'm having a network problem with my Samsung Galaxy Young (S6312) device. Sometimes while trying to make a call, even though the signal indicator shows 2 or 3 bars, the device displays a message like "Not registered on network" and the call doesn't get through.

Also, sometimes while my mobile data is turned on it doesn't connect to the internet. I have set the mobile network to the GSM/WCDMA(AUTO) mode.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem to this. In my case, it was caused by the SIM card coming loose. Try the following steps:-

- Turn the phone off completely
- Remove the SIM card
- Reinsert the SIM card
- Turn the phone on again

and then see if you can make a call and use mobile Internet. If it happens repeatedly, you might need to wedge a small piece of paper in with your SIM card to keep it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an unlocked phone, my Samsung galaxy 2 can do the same thing. I have a Vodafone sim in it, but live in an area that SD does not get a Vodafone signal, only Optus (have Optus Nokia phone also) and the Samsung shows me a full 4 bars, and if I try to make a call it will show network not registered. When I get to an area that I know I will get a Vodafone signal I some times have to go into settings a tell it to use the Vodafone network. A bug as I see it as it knows what sim you have so it should ignore other networks.
Brian